5 axis CNC Milling (Conical Hole on a Cube)


Dear Community,
I am using Camworks Software by Solidworks. I want to mill a conical hole on a cube. This means that the tool have to be tilted to carve out the shape of the conical curve area, which I have done successfully. Now, my hardest part is to mill the flat side (highlighted in yellow) by using tilted tool also. How am I suppose to do that?
I would be glad if someone can help me figure it out :).
Thank you.

maybe the tool should be vertical and have a specialized shape

Lathe the recess. May need multiple cutters to minimize the internal radii. Alternate, split the part into 2 (along the flat interior) and assemble them later.
